# Why is my machine flooding the wireless with LLC protocol packets?

Tags: wireless, dmesg, ath5k, ntop

Shortly after upgrading to the recent kernel 3.2.0-36-generic I started to notice that my wireless connection got seriously jammed:

- Anything over the web (SSH, HTTP(S)) appears to be a bit slow.
- Pinging my access point produces a rather high packet loss rate and even if there is no traffic from other machines in the network the response time ranges from 0.5ms to 300ms.
- Quite commonly the ping says "destination host unreachable".
- Dis- and reconnecting to the AP (WPA2-PSK) is working well, but ping is still complaining about "destination host unreachable".
- Other machines (laptops and smartphones) show no such behavior.
- syslog, dmesg and iw show no suspicious messages.
- Wireshark tells me that -- among some erroneous or lost packets -- my machine is constantly sending LLC, BACnet-APDU and X.25 protocol packets to the MAC address belonging to the laptop of my wife.

You can find output of "wireshark" (48 LLC packets) [here](http://ubuntuone.com/6A954wutGWC5BH97JgQ2vm).

I have tried netstat and ntop in order to find the process responsible for sending those packets, but I was not able to do so.

Could this be my wireless driver (ath5k for Atheros Communications Inc. AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter) or kernel running wild? Or is this simply my wireless card telling me that it is gone???

Some other details on my machine:

- AMD Phenom 9500
- 4GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT
- Xubuntu 12.04 (64bit)
- Atheros Communications Inc. AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter
- Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Comment: Just booted an older kernel (3.2.0-35).
- LLC flood still present.
- but "ping" shows acceptable statistics: 

200 packets transmitted, 188 received, 6% packet loss, time 199036ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.468/2.747/145.535/14.417 ms

Comment: Filed bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1111603

Comment: Disruptions in data connection seems to be an issue specific to kernel 3.2.0-36.

Comment: Doing some extended testing it appears the other device broadcasts one LLC packet, which causes my machine to constantly send replies in the same protocol.

Comment: As this appears to be a bug, this will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).